# Converting non-sendable function value may introduce data races

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, swift-concurrency

I have a simple piece of code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
            .task {
                await myAsyncFunc()
            }
    }

    private func myAsyncFunc() async {}
}
```

This compiles completely fine. However, if I replace the task with this:

```
.task(myAsyncFunc)
```

It doesn't work, and gives me the error below:

> Converting non-sendable function value to '@Sendable () async -> Void' may introduce data races

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it states, the function can be marked as `@Sendable`. This is used to prevent data races.

Change it to this:

```
@Sendable private func myAsyncFunc() async {}
```

*Note that the `@Sendable` must be before the access modifier.*

Comment: `Main actor-isolated synchronous instance method '<#method#>' cannot be marked as '@Sendable'; this is an error in Swift 6`

Comment: Except that it cannot, if the object it belongs to is not sendable itself, as then you will get: `Instance methods of non-Sendable types cannot be marked as '@Sendable'; this is an error in Swift 6`